# issue where a constant value becomes a reference, or re-assigning a constant

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, apollo-client

So i am not entirely sure what is going on or how to explain it but,

TL;DR version, basically this is happening

```js
const {a} = {a: 'd'}

a = "12"
console.log(a)
// returns "12"
```

I am trying to update the state of `publicItemList` to the users input.
Meanwhile `useQuery()` is refetching data every 500ms and updating the value of `data`.

What im expecting to happen is when I change `publicItemList` and the query hook runs itself again, the `publicItemList` state should update to the new value of `data`.
So if i set a box to ticked on `publicItemList`, it should untick again when `useQuery()` runs again, because the tick was never saved to the database.

What is actually happening is when i change `publicItemList` with the tick, is that it unticks when the query hook runs, and the wierdest thing of all...

If i log out `data` `console.log(data[where ever that tick is].isTicked)` it will return what i have changed in `publicItemList`, **how is this even possible?**

```js
  const [publicItemList, setPublicItemList] = useState<ItemProps[]>([])

  const { loading: tripLoading, error: tripError, data, refetch } = useQuery(getTrip, {
    variables: { id: tripId },
    pollInterval: 500,
    notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
    onCompleted: data => {
      const { trip } = data
      const publicList = trip.packingLists.find((x) => x.isPublicList)
      setPublicItemList(publicList.items)
    },
    onError: error => console.log(error),
  })

  const insertPublicItemListSingle = (inputItem: ItemProps, removing?: boolean) => {
    const newItemList: ItemProps[] = publicItemList.slice()
    const foundIndex = newItemList.findIndex(item => item.id === inputItem.id)

    if (foundIndex.toString()) {
      // Update
      newItemList[foundIndex] = inputItem

    setPublicItemList(newItemList)
  }

  const checkItem = (item: ItemProps) => { // <=== this is a user action
    const { packed } = item
    item.packed = !packed
    packed
      ? item.packedBy = ""
      : item.packedBy = userData.name
    insertPublicItemListSingle(item)
  }
```

aditional info,
using Apollo client for react, on react-native on an iOS emulator

Answer (score 1):

In my computer:

```js
const {a} = {a: 'd'}

a = "12"
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.

This is not your problem.
`publicItemList` is an array, we cannot assign it., but we can change the content inside

```js
const a = [1, 2, 4];
a = [2, 4, 6]; // error
a[0] = 2;
a[1]= 4;
a[2] = 6;
cosole.log(a); // [2, 4, 6]
```

In my opinion, `setPublicItemList` don't re-assign your `publicItemList`, it changes the content.

(IDK `react-native`)

Comment: but i am using ``setPublicItemList`` and not re-assigning ``publicItemList``

Comment: Yes, I mean `setPublicItemList` assign content of `publicItemList` (like `publicItemList[0] = newArrray[0]`)

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue, there was a mutation in

```js
  const checkItem = (item: ItemProps) => {
    const { packed } = item
    item.packed = !packed
    packed
      ? item.packedBy = ""
      : item.packedBy = userData.name
    insertPublicItemListSingle(item)
  }
```

Mutations are always something to break your teeth on